# 'underlying' --> 'underlyingly present'?

Tags: word-request

The word underlyingly does not exist in the classical English dictionaries.

I would like to write the following: The crawling is still underlyingly present in the denser regions, where the wringing and kneading occur.

Is there a better word that officially exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your immediate question is to put "underlying" before "crawling."

> The underlying crawling is still present in the denser regions, where the wringing and kneading occur.

This sentence sounds very odd to me. Is this referring to a crawling sensation in a medical symptom description?  If not, you may need more modifications to the sentence  in order to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

"Classical"? It is in the 1973 Merriam-Webster, and the 2007 Oxford Handbook of Cognitive Linguistics.

[Underlyingly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underlyingly)

[image]

Comment: Oxford English Dictionary, Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary, Cambridge, Longman ...